# Maven project Deployment issue

Tags: maven, javafx, pom.xml

I have a maven project and I am importing it in Intellij IDEA. Everything is working fine except when i deploy the maven project console shows the following error

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project multisite: Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter -> [Help 1]

This is my pom.xml file code

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>multisite</groupId>
<artifactId>multisite</artifactId>
<version>1</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>18.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Can someone tell me how to specify maven repository element path in my project or is there anything else i'm missing in pom.xml file ?

@ItachiUchiha: this is complete error i am getting in console now,

```
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building multisite 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:java (default-cli) @ multisite ---
[WARNING]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: src/multisite/Main
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:281)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.144 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-10-30T16:57:08+05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/153M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:java (d
efault-cli) on project multisite: An exception occured while executing the Java
class. src/multisite/Main -> [Help 1]
```

[image]

Comment: How are you trying to deploy your maven project?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha i'm using Intellij IDEA and has run this project in every goal like clean, compile and site but when i run this project using deploy it gives above error

Comment: @HamzaKhalil: Your original question was very different. Let's try to sort out your deployment issues here. I suggest you post a new question with the second issue, as they're not related, despite being Maven-related. Let's do things one by one.

Comment: @carlspring i just got know that deployment is different than compiling a maven project. the goals in maven are really ambiguous to know how to run maven project.

Comment: @HamzaKhalil: The goals are not ambiguous, you're just not sufficiently familiar with Maven yet. If I may suggest, you could have a look at "Maven: The Definitive Guide" and also "Apache Maven 2 Effective Implementation". They're quite good books that help you wrap your head around a number of things. :)

Answer (score 1):

When you are trying to use `mvn deploy` you need to specify the deployment location.

The `deploy` command does the following :

> copies the final package to the remote repository for sharing with other developers and projects.

It can be specified in the pom using the `distributionManagement` tag like this:

```
<distributionManagement>
   <repository>
      <id>nexus-site</id>
      <url>http://central_nexus/server</url>
   </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

For more information go through the docs on [Distribution Management](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Distribution_Management).

Comment: thanks @itachiUchiha: But i just want to run this project on my machine. How can i do that without deploying the project

Comment: Is it a JavaFX project? If yes you can just say `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="complete.package.name.MainClass"`

Comment: Additionally, your IDE should be able to run the project without any additional setting.

Comment: I ran it and now it is showing the error "Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:java (default-cli) on project multisite"

Comment: This is partial error. Can you post the full error?

Comment: Additionally, did you run `mvn compile` before running the exec command?

Comment: please see edited question now. complete error included at end

Comment: Can you add the project structure as well. For example, which of your class extend Application and has the main method() and what it is the package it is contained in. You are most probably passing an invalid value to `mainClass`.

Comment: please see the attached picture in question. That is structure of project

Comment: The command you need to fire is `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="multisite.Main"`. Moreover, if SatelliteClient is extending `Application` then you should call `SatelliteClient.launch(args)` inside your main method. *Make sure your code doesn't have any compilation error*

Comment: Issue still exists bro. Thanks for ur effort :)

Answer (score 1):

You have not specified a proper `<distributionManagement/>` section.

You'll need something like this in your `pom.xml`:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>releases</id>
        <url>https://repository-server/releases</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <url>https://repository-server/snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Apart from that, in your `~/.m2/settings.xml` file you will need to have the following section as well:

```
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>releases</id>
        <username>username-goes-here</username>
        <password>password-goes-here</password>
    </server>
    <server>
        <id>releases</id>
        <username>username-goes-here</username>
        <password>password-goes-here</password>
    </server>
```

Please, note that the `<ìd/>` sections must match each other, as they are a mapping.